# T-SQL - How to use a recursive calculation in a CTE?

Tags: t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I want to calculate the avarage earnings per month of an employee during his time he worked for a company.

I build a recursive CTE based on a similar thread and I get the results only for one employee. What kind of modification do I need to do to make the employee ID variable and to get the same kind of results for every employee in the table?

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE
(
  ID VARCHAR(50) ,
 Earning FLOAT,
  StartDate DATE ,
 EndDate DATE
)INSERT  INTO @tbl
    ( ID, Earning, StartDate, EndDate
SELECT  employee_ID  AS ID   
,([Total Earning]/ (SELECT datediff(MONTH,[EndDate],
[StartDate])+1
FROM [employee_table] WHERE employee_ID = 'EKA-0004562'))
,[StarTDate]
,[EndDate]
FROM [employee_table]
WHERE  employee_ID = 'EKA-0004562'


--final query using recursive cte
;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   T.ID ,
                    T.Earning ,
                    T.StartDate ,
                    T.EndDatum ,
                    CONVERT(DATE, NULL) AS Dt ,
                    n = 0
           FROM     @tbl AS T
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   cte.ID ,
                    cte.Earning ,
                    cte.StartDate ,
                    cte.EndDatum ,
                    DATEADD(MONTH, n, cte.StartDate) ,
                    cte.n + 1
           FROM     cte
           WHERE    n <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, cte.StartDate, cte.EndDatum)
         )
SELECT  cte.ID ,
        cte.Earning,
        dt AS Months
FROM    cte
WHERE   cte.Dt IS NOT NULL
```

**This is my goal:**

Well, I have a table with a lot of data with information concerning employees.
Every employee has a "startdate" (the time when he startet to work for the company) and and "enddate" (the time when he quit the job). 
I would like to write into a table the same count of rows as the employee worked for the company in month. For example:

My basic table:

---

```
Employee Number | StartDate | EndDate | Total Earnings (Total Earnings/(EndDate-StartDate)

4711               20150101   20150523        24110
```

---

This example shows that the employee worked for the company for 5 Month and earned 24110€. In Avarage he earned 4822€ per month.
So I want to insert in the new table 5 rows with the following information:

New Table:

---

```
  Employee Number | StartDate | EndDate      |  AVG Earnings
  row1: 4711               20150101   20150523   4822

  row2: 4711               20150201   20150523   4822

  row3: 4711               20150301   20150523   4822

  row4: 4711               20150401   20150523   4822

  row5: 4711               20150501   20150523   4822
```

Comment: why not just do Select employee_ID, avg(Earning) From [employee_table] Group By ID or Select [Total Earning]/ (datediff(MONTH,[EndDate],
[StartDate])+1)

Comment: Because if the employee is working in the company for 3 month I need 3 rows in the @TBL Table with the formula (Total Earnings / count of month) 

So in this case we would have 3 times in a row "Total Earnings / 3".

Comment: can you add a SQL Fiddle or a query with sample data and output. I am not sure I fully understand your question. (only some data, not thousands of row :) )

Comment: Provide sample data and desired result.

Comment: I edited my first post with the desired sample data. I hope you guys understand what I mean : )

Comment: @Jinks do not forget to accept correct answer for future users.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I think your query seems overly complicated and the recursive CTE is not needed. It may be become inneficient when dealing with a lot of employees and consecutive years.

This query give the correct output for the 2 sample users:

- Sample

  ```
  declare @employee_table table(Employee_Number int, StartDate date, EndDate date, Total_Earnings bigint);
  Insert Into @employee_table(Employee_Number, StartDate, EndDate, Total_Earnings) values
  (4711, '20150101', '20150523', 24110)
  , (4712, '20150101', '20150423', 24110);
  ```
- Query

  ```
  with list(n) as (
      Select ROW_NUMBER() over(Order By n)
      From (
          Select 1 From (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as l1(n)
          Cross Join (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as l2(n)
          Cross Join (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as l3(n)
      ) as l(n)
  )
  Select l.n, e.Employee_Number
      , [StartDate] = DATEADD(MONTH, l.n-1, e.StartDate)
      , [EndDate] = e.EndDate
      , [AVG Earnings] = e.Total_Earnings/(DATEDIFF(MONTH, e.StartDate, e.EndDate)+1)
  From @employee_table as e
  Inner Join list as l on l.n <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, e.StartDate, e.EndDate)+1
  Order By e.Employee_Number, l.n
  ```

> Output

```
n   Employee_Number StartDate   EndDate AVG Earnings
1   4711            2015-01-01  2015-05-23  4822
2   4711            2015-02-01  2015-05-23  4822
3   4711            2015-03-01  2015-05-23  4822
4   4711            2015-04-01  2015-05-23  4822
5   4711            2015-05-01  2015-05-23  4822
1   4712            2015-01-01  2015-04-23  6027
2   4712            2015-02-01  2015-04-23  6027
3   4712            2015-03-01  2015-04-23  6027
4   4712            2015-04-01  2015-04-23  6027
```

> notes:

- @employee_table contains 2 employee. 4711 is similar to your sample
- The list CTE efficiently creates a list from 1 to 1000 which should be good enough for 1000 months (> 83 years)
- The main query uses it to create the list of consecutive months using just a simple INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
create table #test
(
    ID INT,
    StartDate DATE, 
    EndDatum DATE,
    Earning INT
)
insert into #test values
(4711,'20150101','20150523',24110),
(4712,'20150101','20150625',32550)
```

**QUERY**

```
--final query using recursive cte
;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   T.ID ,
                    T.Earning ,
                    T.StartDate ,
                    T.EndDatum ,
                    CONVERT(DATE, NULL) AS Dt ,
                    n = 0
           FROM     #test AS T
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   cte.ID ,
                    cte.Earning ,
                    cte.StartDate ,
                    cte.EndDatum ,
                    DATEADD(MONTH, n, cte.StartDate) ,
                    cte.n + 1
           FROM     cte
           WHERE    n <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, cte.StartDate, cte.EndDatum)
         )
SELECT  cte.ID ,  
        dt StartDate,    
        cte.EndDatum EndDate,       
        cte.Earning / ((DATEDIFF(MONTH, cte.StartDate, cte.EndDatum)) +1) [AVG Earnings]
FROM    cte
WHERE   cte.Dt IS NOT NULL
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ID      StartDate   EndDate     AVG Earnings
4712    2015-01-01  2015-06-25  5425
4712    2015-02-01  2015-06-25  5425
4712    2015-03-01  2015-06-25  5425
4712    2015-04-01  2015-06-25  5425
4712    2015-05-01  2015-06-25  5425
4712    2015-06-01  2015-06-25  5425
4711    2015-01-01  2015-05-23  4822
4711    2015-02-01  2015-05-23  4822
4711    2015-03-01  2015-05-23  4822
4711    2015-04-01  2015-05-23  4822
4711    2015-05-01  2015-05-23  4822
```